# PCRE pattern to count number of character(s)

Tags: regex, pcre

here is my input string:
bar somthing foo bar somthing foo

I would like to count number of a character (ex: 't') between bar & foo
bar somthing foo -> 1
bar somthing foo -> 1

I know we can use 
 /bar(.*?)foo/ 
 and then count number of character in matches[1] with a String function

Is there way to do this w/o string function to count?

Answer (score 1):

A Perl solution:

```
$_ = 'bar test this thing foo';
my $count = /bar(.*?)foo/ && $1 =~ tr/t//;
print $count;
```

Output:

```
4
```

---

Just for fun, using a single expression with `(?{ code })`:

```
$_ = 'bar test this thing foo';

my $count = 0;
/bar ( (?:(?!bar)[^t])*+ ) (?:t (?{ ++$count; }) (?-1) )*+ foo/x or $count = 0;

print $count;
```

Answer (score 0):

@Qtax: the subject says PCRE... so it's not exactly perl. Hence (?{ code }) would most probably be unsupported (let alone the full perl code).
Though both solutions are cool ;)

@tqwer: you can get the match and then replace [^t] with "" and check length..
though i am not sure what the logic behind counting with regex would be ;)